# Bootstrap3 Tooltip When i use inside javascript code it's not fire

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to using Bootstrap3 Tooltip in my calendar javascript code. (You can see screenshot here : http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/163/9eav.jpg)

When i using tooltip a href example outside of calendar div's, it's fire working correctly. But if i use inside my js code like this;

```
var eventTitle = '<a href="'+event.url+'" id="myTooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="'+event.title+'" target="' + eventLinkTarget + '" class="eventTitle">' + useTitle + '</a>';
```

not fire, what is wrong here? Im already using same a classes and id's everythings same but not working inside of javascript codes.

Thanx Cihan.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess, because you suplied very little of your code.

Maybe its related to your usage of `eventLinkTarget` which (following your naming pattern) probably should be `event.LinkTarget`.

Or maybe you are setting up the tooltips at a point where `var eventTitle` is not on your page (retrieved per ajax, for example).

Try to setup your script like this:

```
$(function(){
  //Setup some variables
  var event={};
  event.url="xxx";
  event.title="zzz";
  event.LinkTarget="yyy"
  var useTitle="aaa"
  //create dynamic link
  var eventTitle = '<a href="'+event.url+'" id="myTooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="'+event.title+'" target="' + event.LinkTarget + '" class="eventTitle">' + useTitle + '</a>';

  //append dynamic link somwhere on the page
  $('body').append(eventTitle);
  //apply tooltip to all eventTitles
  $('.eventTitle').tooltip();
  })
```

and everything should work like in this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k12zQGCU4utGROJmatfB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
var eventTitle = '<a href="'+event.url+'" id="myTooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="'+event.title+'" target="' + eventLinkTarget + '" class="eventTitle">' + useTitle + '</a>';

$(eventTitle).tooltip(options);
```

or maybe where ever you bind the `.tooltip(options);` use `.on(` no `.bind(`.